# Failed to Refresh data in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, fragment, refresh, android-recyclerview

I'm using the `RecyclerViewAdapter`. It's perfectly working.

My problem comes in when I am trying to populate the list from the server.

My `DataHandaling` class, I am trying to get the array to refresh the ListView from here...

```
void getEvents() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(enviroClass.url() + "/api/events/" + 7)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request)
            .enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        JSONObject eventObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        JSONArray eventJsonArray = eventObject.getJSONArray("events");
                        System.out.println(eventJsonArray.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
                            eventObject = eventJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            eventObject = eventObject.getJSONObject("event");
                            eventArray.add(new Object_Event(eventObject.getString("name"), eventObject.getString("address"), eventObject.getString("image"), "100" ,eventObject.getString("start_date"), eventObject.getString("end_date"), eventObject.getInt("id")));
                        }
                        System.out.println("This is from the http request in the datahandeling class" + "\n" + eventArray.get(0).getName());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

`Adapter Class` I do have a method here to refresh the view

(**NOTE**: I have no idea if the swap method will work because I can't try it.)

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.garethbecker.socializer.EventListFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener;
import com.app.garethbecker.socializer.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.data;

/**
 * {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that can display a {@link DummyItem} and makes a call to the
 * specified {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}.
 * TODO: Replace the implementation with code for your data type.
 */
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Object_Event> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Object_Event> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void swap(String hello){
//        mValues.clear();
//        DataHandaling dh = new DataHandaling();
//        System.out.println("This is the name of the event from the adapter" + "\n" + dh.getEventArray().get(0).getName());
//        mValues.addAll(eventArray);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();

        System.out.println(hello);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).getId() + "");
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getName());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public Object_Event mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

`Fragment` class

(**NOTE**: This should be done right because it does initially populate the ListView)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.garethbecker.socializer.dummy.DummyContent;
import com.app.garethbecker.socializer.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.data;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class EventListFragment extends Fragment {

    DataHandaling dh = new DataHandaling();


    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public EventListFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static EventListFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        EventListFragment fragment = new EventListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(dh.getEventArray(), mListener));
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(int item);
    }
```

I try to (refresh list) refresh data which i fetch from server.where I am failing miserably.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I found out what I was doing wrong...

I changed the constructor of MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter (Which I should rename) so that it checked the values to check if they are null.

```
public MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Object_Event> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    if (items != null) {
        mValues = items;
    }
    if (listener != null ) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then I called the swap method without any difficulty

```
MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(null, null);
adapter.swap(eventArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify the change.

```
MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I did that in the swap method, But I have no idea how to call it from data hadaling???